# Best way to generically convert SQL-Based classes to DTO using Class Name in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a collection of classes in a SQL database that all share the same structure, and cannot be changed. They are similar to the example below.

[image]

I am using Entity Framework Core and would like to have one set of code which can handle the crud for each of these tables. I've tried to generically the dto object back to the entity-framework generated class based on the table name saved in the DTO in the past, but had little luck.

I haven't found a way to convert the following class to a generic type using reflection below would be an example of the class I would like to convert to the type below it without having a switch statement or pre-defined mappings:

```
DTOClass
{
   Id;
   ShortName;
   LongName;
   TableName;
}

EmployeeType
{
   Id;
   ShortName;
   LongName;
   TableName;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could have created the six classes for those tables in less time than it took me to write this comment. CRUD is automatically handled by EF. What are you hoping to gain by adding complexity?

Comment: @RikD You are correct, but I have simplified the problem I am trying to solve in order to focus on the question, which is how to convert one type to another using a value at runtime.

Comment: Anyway, though the *why* question is interesting (“is it a good approach to create an abstraction for these data classes?”, the *how* question is off-topic here since we don’t assist with code questions.

Comment: @RikD Good point, I should ask over in Stack Overflow. As to the why, there are a couple reasons: 1: Consider the number of tables to be somewhere between 1-1000. 2: If another one of these tables is added, I want to be able to have to change nothing at the presentation layer or service layer. My hope would be to have a url with the table name be used with the same set of code all the way down to the data layer, where we might need to change some code.

Comment: Then how would EF know that there is a table exist for that model?

Comment: Sounds like someone is committing the no-no of "storing in a table name that which should be in a column" i.e. have one table in the DB calld Enums with a EnumType column that has values like 'Employee', 'Job' etc.. You could use a view to combine it up - if you add a table, add another line to the view... You could even go the other way and have one table and N views that mimic the tables, eg `CREATE VIEW JobType AS SELECT Id, Short, Long FROM Enums WHERE EnumType = 'Job'` but ultimately, given that all these things look and smell the same, can you not just inherit from one common entity/dto?

Comment: If you have the database tables, you can use scaffolding to have EF generate the corresponding classes.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Create an interface for the common fields (which in this case seems to be all of them).

```
interface INamedType
{
    int    Id { get; set; }
    string ShortName { get; set; }
    string LongName { get; set; }
}
```

Step 2. Let the EF generate separate models for your entities.

Step 3. Add the interface to the entities you wish to have under common code. Since EF classes are `partial`, you can do this in your own class file within your project.

```
partial class EmployeeType : INamedType
{
}
partial class JobType : INamedType
{
}
//etc.
```

Step 4. Now you can write common code for any entity that implements `INamedType`.

```
void PrintShortName(INamedType type)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"The type's short name is {type.ShortName}");
}

void Foo()
{
    PrintShortName(myEmployeeType);
    PrintShortName(myJobType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do something like this myself, and of course I used reflection to do it.  Here is the code I used, with an explanation below:

```
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<(Type, Type), (PropertyInfo, PropertyInfo)[]> PICache =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<(Type, Type), (PropertyInfo, PropertyInfo)[]>();

    public static E2 EntityCopy<E1, E2>(E1 from, E2 to)
    {
        var types = (fromType: typeof(E1), toType: typeof(E2));
        if (PICache.TryGetValue(types, out var props))
        {
            foreach ((var p1, var p2) in props)
            {
                p2.SetValue(to, p1.GetValue(from));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PropertyInfo[] GetOrderedProps(Type t) => t.GetProperties().OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToArray();
            var e1_props = GetOrderedProps(types.fromType);
            var e2_props = GetOrderedProps(types.toType);
            var props_new = new List<(PropertyInfo, PropertyInfo)>();

            var i1 = 0; var i2 = 0;
            while (i1 < e1_props.Count() && i2 < e2_props.Count())
            {
                var p1 = e1_props[i1]; var p2 = e2_props[i2];

                if (p1.Name == p2.Name)
                {
                    if (!p2.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(KeyAttribute))
                        && !(p2.PropertyType.Name.Contains("ICollection"))
                        && p1.GetMethod != null
                        && p2.SetMethod != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            p2.SetValue(to, p1.GetValue(from));
                            props_new.Add((p1, p2));
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Log(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    i1++; i2++;
                }
                else if (string.Compare(p1.Name, p2.Name) < 0) { i1++; }
                else { i2++; }
            }
            PICache.TryAdd(types, props_new.ToArray());
        }
        return to;
    }
```

Here, `PICache` is caching an ordered array of pairs of `PropertyInfo`s.  The idea is that the first time we see a pair of `Type`s, we will go through the properties in a specific order (here I've ordered by name) and match the source property to the destination property.  Once we've done this once the properties and their ordering are cached for perfomance.

You should be able to see some caveats here.  I am not copying any `ICollection` property, since I am using EF6 with lazy loading.  If I were to copy these properties I could end up loading data from the database I don't want, which massively impacts performance.  I am also not copying the Key, which you may want to do.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to extend the Dbcontext with a generic method that returns the DTO. `context.GetDTO<Table>().Select(x=> new DTO() {Id = x.Id, ShortName = x.ShortName, LongName = x.LongName }).ToList()`

Comment: This would only return a list of new, empty `DTO` objects with default-initialised fields - it wouldn't map any of the data across.

Comment: The OP will have to do the mapping to the new DTO object. I have edited the answer to show the mapping...